# try to add a module to python lib on os x system but the folder /usr/local/bin/lib cannot be found

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to add a module to my python library. On windows system, it usually goes into a folder called "lib" but I cannot find this folder on osx. I have try "/usr/local/bin/lib" but nothing popped up. Then I looked into the folder /usr/local/bin/ and noticed that there is not a file named "lib".
How can I add additional modules to python?
The modules come will the python (which are supposed to in "lib" such as "math" work fine. i.e. import math still works).
I use tkinter with Tcl/Tk to install the python.

Comment: On UNIX/Linux systems, it's usually `/usr/local/lib/python<version>` or `/usr/lib/python<version`. I'd guess that OSX follows this (but I've never used it). The `bin` directory is only for binaries you actually execute; it typically doesn't have any subdirectories.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But the /usr/local/lib/ cannot be found either.